# 'Hit on someone' means like 'flirt with someone'. Then when I wanna make the tone stronger, can i put 'up' like

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Hit **up** on someone

is it ok in american english, or british english?

or it would be ok but as a native(american or english), almost no one say 'hit up on someone'? 99% says 'hit on someone' only?

Thanks teachers:)

Comment: I for one have never heard that. "Hit up" means something else.

Comment: Teachers will tell you to use standard capitalisation, YS.

Comment: To "hit upon" (not "hit up on") means to discover something: "They hit upon a way to turn waste water into fertilizer."

Comment: @Robusto That said, "hit upon" is not something I've ever heard.  People say "happened upon", "came upon", or just "found".

Comment: @JRodge01 I have definitely heard and seen it, but to me it has a slightly different meaning than _happen upon_ or the other options you mention. _Happen upon_ means to encounter or see something by chance; _hit upon_ means to make a new discovery by chance. You happen upon an amazing backalley restaurant; you hit upon a cure for cancer (while trying to make cough drops, say).

Answer (score 1):

"Hit on" means to flirt.  "Hit up" means to initiate contact.  "Hit up on someone" is not something people say.

You could say "coming on" to someone, which is a bit more sexual than "hitting on".  "Courting" is a more formal process of flirting and dating with the purpose of marriage.

Answer (score 1):

There are three idiomatic phrasal verbs:

1. **[hit on](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_on)** - meaning to flirt : "John fancied Susan the moment he saw her, so he hit on her."
2. **[hit up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_up)** - meaning to request (someone) to do or give something : "John hit me up for more money."
3. **[hit upon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_upon)** - meaning to mention or address; to suddenly have an idea; to discover something by chance : John will hopefully hit upon all of the customers' concerns during the meeting.

Your suggested usage of "hit up on" isn't idiomatic.  It is not an emphatic version of "hit on."  I don't see anyone inferring that meaning from the words themselves.

Answer (score 0):

**hit on**. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87336?redirectedFrom=hit%20on#eid1671238)

> colloquial (originally U.S.). to hit on: to make romantic or sexual
>   advances towards.

To make hitting on someone seem or sound more emphatic in written form consider adding an exclamation point!  Other senses of hitting off, out, around have different meanings.